# multiple x-windows for the same vim-server instance

Tags: vim

I have several different projects open in different vim windows so that I can have on project open in each of my two monitors, but I need to have a large number of projects open and navigating between so many instances of gvim is awkward.

I want a system where I can have two x-windows open on the same vim server, sharing the same buffers and registers, etc. Is this at all possible?

Comment: I am not sure if this is ok for you. so I put it in comment. You want different projects share buffers, registers. how about open single vim instance, and for each project create a tab. in each tab you could have its own NerdTree, tagbar, split whatever. In this way buffers are shared, projects are separated in tabs.

Comment: Thanks, although the whole problem here is that displaying a single x-window over two monitors is awkward to untennable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in Vim. I think *Emacs* has this separation, where you can connect multiple clients to a single server.

I'd suggest using one instance of Vim for each project.